# Solving equation with natural numbers

Tags: problem-solving

I have the following question:
In a store I want to pay with exactly 50 coins. There are 2€, 1€, 0,5€ 0,2€ and 0,1€ coins.
So I'd have
2*a + 1*b + 0,5*c + 0,2*d + 0,1*e = amount I have to pay
And a+b+c+d+e=50 (number of coins)
Since there are no half Euros, a,b,c,d, and e are natural numbers (0-50)

Is there any way to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the amount you have to pay a whole number too or a decimal?

Comment: A decimal number

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the amount you want to pay. For example, if the amount is $0.01$, you do not have a coin with that "resolution". Moreover, if the amount you want to pay is $0.1$, you can only pay with your $0.1$ coin, because you don't have any coins with lower value to combine. Finally, there are amounts you do not have the money for: if something costs $\$1000000$, you don't have a coin with a high enough value such that fifty of it will give you a million dollars. In summary, with the information you have given us, it seems that the problem is underspecified.

Comment: The amount I want to pay is about 63,x0.

Comment: How much exactly? 63.001 is unsolvable, for example.

Comment: No, I know 63.001 is unsolvable because there isn't a 0.001€ coin.
Assuming I want to pay all in coins in a real store only using coins but it should be 50 coins exactly.